# String formatting itertools output - Tuple out of range error

Tags: python, format, python-itertools

I'm trying to output the result of an outer product to a file using map and itertools, I'm struggling to understand why this produces an index error.

```
import itertools
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
with open('job.list', 'w') as l:
    map(lambda x: l.write("{0} {1}\n".format(x)), itertools.product(a, b))
```

Changing the map to

```
map(lambda x: l.write("{0} {1}\n".format(x[0], x[1])), itertools.product(a, b))
```

removes the error, but this is obviously imperfect.

I guessed this error was  to do with itertools.product returning an iterator rather than a list. But trying

```
map(lambda x: l.write("{0} {1}\n".format([d for d in x])), itertools.product(a, b))
```

instead still causes the index error.

Clearly there is a gap in my understanding here, but I could do with some help seeing what it is.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with `map` and `lambda`? It looks like you could do this with a `for` loop which would be more readable.

Comment: Does `map(lambda x: l.write("{0} {1}\n".format(*x)), itertools.product(a, b))` do what you want?

Comment: It's a pretty rote throw away input generator script for a specific job going to an HPC I will be running once. As a learning exercise I've tried to write it as tersely as possible using map and lambda. I agree if this were ever to go to anyone else or be used for more than just this one run then I would use the more readable solution. Either way, I'd like to understand my error.

Comment: And yes, roganjosh, it does. Clearly I need to learn more about the *operator. Thanks.

Comment: Does that want to be posted as an answer to be accepted then? Or will the question be killed now?

Comment: I have posted as an answer, I just wanted to clarify first that I had solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that `format` in `"{0} {1}\n".format(x)` is expecting two values to insert into `{0}` and `{1}`. However, you only provide one - `x` - and it doesn't know that it should use the individual items in that iterable. Instead, you can use the splat operator `*` to unpack the tuple:

```
map(lambda x: l.write("{0} {1}\n".format(*x)), itertools.product(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the argument or the format string so they match. The former approach was posted by @roganjosh. This is the latter alternative:

```
"{0[0]} {0[1]}\n".format(x)
```

Comment: This is interesting. I hadn't realised the format specifies could index collection elements. Also good to see that this works with a dictionary's keys as well. Thanks!